# Stricter type hinting for overridden parent method?

Tags: php, inheritance, type-hinting

Consider the following to classes:

```
class objectCollection implements Iterator {

  private $objectArray = [];
  private $position = 0;


  public function __construct() {
      $this->position = 0;
  }

  public function add( $object ){
    if(!in_array( $object, $this->objectArray))
      $this->objectArray[] = $object;
    return $this;
  }

  public function remove( $object ){
    if(($key = array_search( $object, $this->objectArray())) !== false)
      unset($this->objectArray[$key]);
    return $this;
  }

  public function rewind() {
      $this->position = 0;
  }

  public function current() {
      return $this->objectArray[$this->position];
  }

  public function key() {
      return $this->position;
  }

  public function next() {
      ++$this->position;
  }

  public function valid() {
      return isset($this->objectArray[$this->position]);
  }

}

class attachmentCollection extends objectCollection {

  public function add( attachment $attachment ){
    return parent::add($attachment);
  }

  public function remove( attachment $attachment ){
    return parent::remove($attachment);
  }

}
```

This produces the follwing error:
Declaration of attachmentCollection::add() should be compatible with objectCollection::add($object)

When you look at the code, I think it's rather obvious what I am trying to do.
I want the `attachmentCollection` to essentially be the same as the `objectCollection`, except that the objects that can be added ( or removed ) need to be an instance of `attachment`.

What is the right way to do this ?

Comment: as far as i know, php does not support overloading in the same manner as it will be done by higher languages...those must have the same signature...

Comment: Oh, ok. That's a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP errored code](https://eval.in/759636)

[PHP working code](https://eval.in/759637)

Change this to

```
public function add( $object ){
    if(!in_array( $object, $this->objectArray))
      $this->objectArray[] = $object;
    return $this;
  }


public function remove( $object ){
    if(($key = array_search( $object, $this->objectArray())) !== false)
      unset($this->objectArray[$key]);
    return $this;
  }
```

This

```
public function add(attachment $object ){
    if(!in_array( $object, $this->objectArray))
      $this->objectArray[] = $object;
    return $this;
 }
public function remove(attachment $object ){
    if(($key = array_search( $object, $this->objectArray())) !== false)
      unset($this->objectArray[$key]);
    return $this;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Of course this gets rid of the error, but I wan't to be able to extend other classes from the objectCollection with different type hinting.
Like a 'productCollection' for example, where the 'add' method only accepts 'product' objects

Comment: @minychillo If you are using `strict_types` then you have to follow it in parent classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody has a better solution, here is what I went with ( still open to a better solution ):

```
class attachmentCollection extends objectCollection {

  public function add( $attachment ){
    if(! $attachment instanceof attachment) throw new \Exception('Argument must be instance of attachment');
    return parent::add($attachment);
  }

  public function remove( $attachment ){
    if(! $attachment instanceof attachment) throw new \Exception('Argument must be instance of attachment');
    return parent::remove($attachment);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the case you want to extend further classes from the objectClass  and the methods should be compatible, then i would recommend to use an Interface as the passed parameter, for example:

```
interface collection{     
   //your methods
}

class objectCollection implements Iterator {

    private $objectArray = [];
    private $position = 0;

    public function add(collection $object){
      if(!in_array( $object, $this->objectArray))                       
        $this->objectArray[] = $object;
        return $this;
    }

    public function remove(collection $object ){
       if(($key = array_search( $object, $this->objectArray())) !==false)
        unset($this->objectArray[$key]);
        return $this;
    }
  ....
}


 class attachmentCollection extends objectCollection {

    public function add(collection $attachment ){
       return parent::add($attachment);
    }

    public function remove( collection $attachment ){
       return parent::remove($attachment);
    }

 }

 class productCollection extends objectCollection {

     public function add(collection $attachment ){ 
        return parent::add($attachment);
     }

     public function remove(collection $attachment ){
         return parent::remove($attachment);
     }

 }


 class attachment  implements  collection {
    //implement interface methods
 }

class product implements collection{
   //implement interface methods 
 }
```